# Postgresql, Delete characters within strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and am attempting to create a query that will clean up certain columns within a table.  By "clean up" I mean delete all characters before or after a certain symbol.

I have one column called "Campaign" within a table called "Adwords".The column has this string/structure within all rows, DE-SRC-Brand.  The only place that I would like to keep in this column would be where Brand currently is.  I had previously done this manually through excel by doing a simple search and replace with "*-" as the searching criteria.

How would this formula translate to PostgreSQL?  How would it then also change if I would like to delete characters in front of a certain designated symbol.  Please let me know if anything is unclear as I am still new to this program.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The description is rather abstract.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/1920232) and provide sample data and the exact desired outcome based on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the brand, you can use `substring()` with a pattern:

```
select substring(campaign from '%-%-#"%#"' for '#') as brand
from adwords;
```

You can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update adwords
    set campaign = substring(campaign from '%-%-#"%#"' for '#')
    where campaign like '%-%-%';
```

Comment: Hello, That worked perfect.  I am however not entirely sure what exactly that did though.  What if I would like to remove characters following a certain symbol?  As an example if I had Brand {e} and I was trying to eliminate all occurances of match type which would start with "{.  Thank you for the help.  -Ian